# Vaadin 6 combo box linked with enum

Tags: gwt, vaadin

I wanted to know if there is a way to assign the select items all the values of an enum instead of manually adding each one of them.Currently I do this:

```
ComboBox myBox = new ComboBox();
for(SelectValuesEnum enum: SelectValuesEnum.values()){
 myBox.addItem(enum)
}
```

Comment: there is `addItems` since 7.2; and the IndexedContainer seems not to have a handy shortcut.  if you do this alot write your own container or your own combobox to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

With this you get a List with all enum values

```
new ArrayList<MyEnum>(Arrays.asList(SelectValuesEnum.values()));
```

And this you can convert it into a Collection and use it in the ComboBox constructor which accepts a Collection as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple BeanContainer:

```
                BeanContainer<Integer, YouEnum> cbContainer =  new BeanContainer<Integer, YouEnum>(YouEnum.class);
                cbContainer.setBeanIdProperty("id");
                cbContainer.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(YouEnum.class));

                ComboBox cb = new ComboBox(null, cbContainer);
                cb.setItemCaptionPropertyId("fieldDescription");
                cb.setImmediate(true);

                // return cb;



public enum YouEnum {
    VAL_1("value 1"),
    VAL_2("value 2");

    private final String fieldDescription;

    private YouEnum(String value) {
        fieldDescription = value;
    }

    public String getFieldDescription() {
        return fieldDescription;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return String.valueOf(ordinal());
    }
}
```